# How to find where I have set "umask 077"?

Tags: debian, umask

When logged in as `root`, I have `umask` set to `077` which causes problems (such as `/etc/resolv.conf` being unreadable for non-root and thus `DNS` not working.

I don't know where I have set the umask `077`. It is not set in `.bashrc` or in `.profile` or in `/etc/profile`.

Any suggestions where `077` might come from?

I am using Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man bash`, in the **INVOCATION** section:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter‐
>          active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com‐
>          mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>          exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
>          shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Make sure to check all the files mentioned there.

However, I don't see how `umask` is a "problem" here. The fact that you have `0077` just means that all files *created* during your interactive shell will be non-accessible by group and other users. In itself, there's nothing *wrong* with that, it's very safe for your `root` user. If you need, you can always make a file accessible by other users, all you need is a `chmod`, for example:

```
chmod +r /etc/resolv.conf
```

Note that `umask` doesn't affect existing files. For example:

```
$ rm -f ls.out
$ umask 077; ls > ls.out; ls -l ls.out
-rw-------  1 jack  staff  341 Dec 31 19:20 ls.out
$ umask 022; ls > ls.out; ls -l ls.out
-rw-------  1 jack  staff  341 Dec 31 19:20 ls.out
```

So it's possible that at some point you tested your network setup in your shell, for example by running `ifup wlan0`, and due to your `umask` the `/etc/resolv.conf` file got created too restrictive. Since then on, even if the file is truncated by a non-interactive shell, the permissions stay the same.

I don't know for sure if non-interactive shells use that restrictive `umask`. Maybe, maybe not. So it's worth checking the files mentioned in the **INVOCATION** section of `man bash`. If the snippet I pasted doesn't help, read through the entire section. You could also check these matches:

```
grep -r umask.*77 /etc/
```

Finally, although `umask 0077` seems nice and secure, maybe it's just too much. When you install something new and play with getting the initial setup right, it's easily possible that you will have similar problems again. I also have Debian/Wheezy and it's `0022` in mine, which I think is the normal default. So when you find where this is set, it's probably ok to change it back to `0022`.

Comment: well, it looks that my `umask` settings affects non-interactive shells as well. How else can you explain, that when I start my network (`ifup wlan0`), the file `/etc/resolv.conf` gets created with 600 permissions. I know, of course, that I can change it with `chmod`. But that only solves the symptom, not the underlying problem.

Comment: @MartinVegter I added more explanation and suggestions to my post

Answer (score 2):

You can find a detailed umask description [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) and [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch01.en.html#_control_of_permissions_for_newly_created_files_umask)

You can check umask value for current login session by `umask` command. This would be only applicable for current session. If you want to make it permanent you can make an entry to `.profile`.
By default it is defined under `/etc/login.defs`. or `/etc/profile`

Comment: thanks, but how does it help to solve my problem ?

Comment: @MartinVegter With the edit it might, but I agree, the original answer was decidedly non-helpful to your question since you obviously know what the umask is and does.